# Elasticsearch Aggregations: Comparing Two Aggregate Buckets

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I am having a difficult time trying to compare the results of two aggerates. More specifically, I want to find unique "keys" between two aggerate buckets. For example, I have the two aggregates on the sample web logs data:

Aggregate 1:

```
GET /kibana_sample_data_logs/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "agent": "Mozilla/4.0"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "IPs": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "clientip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Aggregate 2:

```
GET /kibana_sample_data_logs/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "query": {
    "match_phrase": {
      "agent": "Mozilla/5.0"
    }
  }, 
  "aggs": {
    "IPs": {
      "terms": { 
        "field": "clientip"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the resulting buckets, is there a way to create a third aggregate of IPs that are in the first aggregate but not the second or visa-versa? Preferably in a single API request?

I have tried to use sub-aggregations and scripts but not made any progress.

Thanks!